# rightBarButtonItem appearing in the centre of NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I want to display a BarButtomItem on the right of the nav Bar.
This is what I did:

```
let imageSearch = UIImage(named: "search")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let searchBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: imageSearch, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSearch))
    searchBarButtonItem.width = 20
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarButtonItem
```

When I run the app, the Bar Button Item is in the middle and not on the right side as I want to.
I also tried:

```
navigationItem.setRightBarButton(searchBarButtonItem, animated: true)
```

But it doesn't solve the problem.

EDIT: 
I added the NavigationController programmatically in the Scene Delegate since I'm not using storyboards

Comment: Please, provide more code if you add a navigation bar with it or you add with Storyboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As per my experience, You have faced this issue because you're added large size images for all `resolution 1X, 2X and 3X`. You need
>   to scale it down to a size more appropriate for the navigation bar.

## Solution: 1

You need to scale it down to a size more appropriate for the navigation bar. Please have look image sizes for `UINavigationBar`

> For 1X image Size: 24X24
>
> For 2X image Size: 48X48
>
> For 3X image Size: 72X72

## Solution: 2

If you want to go with the same images then you need to do below changes in your code.

You just need to add `UIImageView` inside the `UIView` then everything
works as expected.

## Code:

```
    let containerView = UIControl(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    containerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSearch), for: .touchUpInside)
    let imageSearch = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    imageSearch.image = UIImage(named: "search")
    containerView.addSubview(imageSearch)                
    let searchBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: containerView)
    searchBarButtonItem.width = 20
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarButtonItem
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the second solution solved the problem!

Comment: Glad to hear! fourth time in a day :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the size of your image. It's probably too large. You'll notice that if you use one of the system images that the button has the correct placement.

```
    let imageSearch = UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
    let searchBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: imageSearch, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    searchBarButtonItem.width = 20
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarButtonItem
```

What you need to do is scale you image down to an appropriate size.